# Правильно ли в тексте употреблено слово "гезамткунстверк"? Он может "случаться"?

Tags: выбор-слов

[Для справки](http://www.wassilykandinsky.ru/gesamtkunstwerk.php):

> **Гезамткунстверк** – это термин, введенный в обращение композитором Рихардом Вагнером в середине 19 века. Его дословное значение –
> совокупное художественное произведение. Этим понятием Вагнер стремился
> описать «искусство будущего», которое виделось ему как синтез,
> объединение всех видов искусств. Данная концепция брала начало из
> панэстетических позиций романтизма. Для Вагнера конкретным воплощением
> этого синтеза были музыкальные драмы, постановки с использованием
> специфических сценических средств.

[Или](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA):

> **Единое произведение искусства** (нем. Gesamtkunstwerk [gə.zamtˌku̇nstˌveɐ̯k]) — всеобъемлющее (универсальное) произведение
> искусства, объединяющее различные виды искусства в рамках единого
> художественного объекта. Для обозначения Гезамткунстверк используются
> понятия "универсальное произведение искусства", "идеальное
> произведение искусства", "единое произведение искусства", "тотальное
> произведение искусства", "синтетическое произведение искусства". В
> качестве основы Гезамткунстверк использует концепцию возвышенного, что
> является важной составляющей идеологии Нового времени.

У меня:

> Зря ведь туристы бросают в автомат монетки, чтоб ненадолго им включили
> электрический свет. На «Обращение Савла» нужно смотреть в полутьме,
> вот как есть – в тусклом луче из окна, в колеблющемся пламени свечей.
> И пусть там давно уже копия. Оригинал исчез или похищен ещё при жизни
> Караваджо и снова им повторён. Но **именно там случается тот самый
> пресловутый гезамткунстверк, о котором говорил Вагнер** в середине XIX
> столетия. Сие замысловатое словечко – гезамт-кунст-верк – ещё раньше
> схватила история искусств и ввела как термин в науку это размывание
> границ между мирами. Это почти мистическое ощущение целостного.
> Цитирую: «Единение искусств, идея художественного преображения
> действительности, методом воздействия всех жанров искусств» – таково
> точное определение, данное этому явлению ещё в 1801 году.

Нижнюю цитату я не обнаружила и не знаю, что делает запятая перед "методом"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дорогая Галина!

С моей точки зрения, автор здесь просто выделывается, если не сказать сильнее. Ему захотелось щегольнуть заморским словечком Gesamtkunstwerk, которому здесь не место.

[На ум приходит анекдот о том, как Петька спросил Василия Ивановича, что это за иностранное слово "ньюанс".]

Как я понимаю, Gesamtkunstwerk -- это единение различных видов искусства в рамках одного художественного объекта (скажем, единение оперного пения, актёрской игры, мощнй фабулы и декораций). Здесь же при правильном рассмотрении (и освещении) картины происходит прорыв в незримое -- вот что важно. И вспоминаются уже не Петька и Василий Иванович, а Фома и Андрей Рублёв из бессмертного фильма: "Сколько тебе говорить, что только через молитву путь от видимого к невидимому идёт."

Попробуйте убедить автора убрать ненужный Gesamtkunstwerk. Можно, конечно утверждать, что здесь Gesamtkunstwerk есть сочетание картины и верного освещения -- но это будет несколько притянуто за уши. Если автору совсем невмоготу без умного термина, согласиться ли он заменить Gesamtkunstwerk на проверенный посконный "катарсис"?

Comment: Мерси, Майклушко! Можно попросить ещё об одном усилии (если оно уже не приложено): глянуть и, быть может, что-то прочесть об «Обращении Савла» Караваджо? Может, этот гезамт как-то можно - хоть за уши - притянуть? Ведь говорилось о К. как о водоразделе на до и после (из-за чего мы и подрались маленько), может, революцию какую в светотени свершил + ещё что угодно (имманентное)? https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Conversion_on_the_Way_to_Damascus-Caravaggio_(c.1600-1).jpg?uselang=ru

Comment: Здеь напрашивается слово "прозрение". (Может быть, "откровение".) Как сюда присобачить вагнеровский Gesamtkunstwerk -- ума не приложу

Comment: Спасибо. Щас всё отправлю автору: возьму за грудки.

Comment: Сочетание мощнейшего библейского сюжета, глубочайшей идеи, и (по тем временам) новаторской живописи -- тянет ли это на Gesamtkunstwerk? По правде, с трудом. Ну ведь не это имел Вагнер в виду, вводя этот термин

Answer (score 1):

1) **"...именно там случается тот самый пресловутый гезамткунстверк"**.  То есть случается (происходит) нечто мистическое.

СЛУЧИТЬСЯ, св. 1. Произойти, совершиться.

Можно сказать "происходит тот самый пресловутый гезамткунстверк", но "случается" смотрится эффектнее, хотя кажется немного авторским сочетанием.

Пример:

Однако затем **случается (= происходит) нечто таинственное** и до конца не осмысленное. [А. А. Ахматова. «Каменный гость» Пушкина (1947)

**2) "Единение искусств,** идея художественного преображения действительности методом воздействия всех жанров искусств» – таково точное определение, данное этому явлению ещё в 1801 году.

Думаю, что запятая случайная, объяснить ее сложно.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы выбрал глагол, который подходит по смыслу к "единению искусств" или к "всеобъемлющему искусству" - в качестве сбывшейся мечты или идеи:

> Но именно там **осуществляется** столь желанный для многих
>   *гезамткунстверк*, предвосхищенный Вагнером в середине XIX столетия.

Comment: Вики: *Принцип единого или синтетического произведения искусства, в частности, реализован в культуре Возрождения — например, в творчестве Микеланджело. Его работы подразумевали использование специфики разных видов искусства: скульптуры, живописи, архитектуры, инженерии. Произведения мастера формируются как единый объект, где соединены разные жанры искусства*. А где что-то подобное у Караваджо? Есть ли явление гезамткунстверка? Саша, разберись, пожалуйста.

Comment: А вот оценки Караваджо - уже на совести автора. Он имеет отношение к искусствоведению? Я-то подумал, что там происходят современные  мероприятия чуть ли не со светомузыкой (Скрябин это соединял с похожей идеей единения искусств).

Comment: Ой-ё! Влипнем мы с гезамптом. Есть просто Караваджо, с его игрой света. Всё.

Comment: Тогда автор перестарался, если назвал этим словом живопись в сочетании со включением-выключением света.