# "Загоняя лошадей, кидая их падалью..."?

Tags: выбор-слов, точное-словоупотребление

> Этот человек к тому же отличался и крайним бесстрашием, в молодости он
>   всегда путешествовал в одиночестве, рассматривая встречи с
>   разбойниками как возможность поразмяться. И, **загоняя лошадей, кидая
>   их падалью, тотчас покупая новую**, он мог передвигаться по своим
>   землям с редчайшей для тех времен скоростью.

Кроме как "питаться падалью", я других глаголов в связи не знаю... Так что делал с загнанными лошадьми наш бесстрашный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*И, загоняя лошадей, кидая их падалью, тотчас покупая новую, он мог передвигаться по своим землям с редчайшей для тех времен скоростью.*

Видимо, это сравнение в форме творительного падежа: кидать в качестве падали, как падаль. Странно для нас, но понятно. Ваш автор - неплохой стилист.

Только мне не нравится здесь множественное число. Загоняет-то он одну лошадь и тут же покупает новую, или уж везде множественное.

Comment: Люсенька, значит можно?! СПАСИБО! Автор будет тронут, а то, говорит, я затравила его...

Comment: Может, не кидая, а бросая? Правда, все равно не нравится – наверно, не дорос я до такого стиля. )

Answer (score 2):

*Падаль* является таковой не по причине "броска" или даже физического спотыкания: живность в свой последний час *падает **замертво***. Правильнее было бы "**оставляя их падалью**"; видимо, допустимо и "бросая" (в аналогичном переносном смысле), - без "кидалова" (у автора вышел геометрико-метафорический диссонанс). В состоянии падали почившую живность находят падальщики (те, кто питается мертвечиной =падалью, объедками после хищников).

Answer (score 1):

И, загнав очередную лошадь, он тотчас покупал новую взамен павшей и потому мог передвигаться по своим землям с редчайшей для тех времен скоростью.

Comment: Мишелик, у меня - книга: я не могу попредложеньево переписывать. Автор родом из Питера - не дайте опозориться земляку, помогите с Gesamtkunstwerk'ом! https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450325/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%9E%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: Дорогая Галина! Первое впечатление -- самое верное. После сорока лет корректорского труда Вы вовсе даже не случайно споткнулись об этот противоестественный оборот. Наработанная десятилетиями интуиция не подвела Вас. "Кидая их падалью" -- это плохой стиль.  Это ненужная вычурность. КГАМ, как говорит молодёжь.

Comment: У, негодяй. Корректором обозвал. А што я тебе сделала? Диплом редактора у меня пылился с незапамятных времён, а Перестройка дала флаг в руки: играй, дитя, пока играется (читай: редакторствуй, коль кому охота с тобой дело иметь). Так что таки да - редактор-то я исчо молоденький... Хочешь поговорить о стихах - милости прошу (только ЛОшка там уже выдана): *Можете ли Вы пересказать “сюжет” ахмадулинского стихотворения, наполненного архаизмами и церковнославянизмами?* - ссылка не уместилась, приди по поиску.

Comment: Дорогая Галина! Прочитал ахмадуллинский стих. Это очень хорошая и вечно современная вариация на тему библейской притчи о пророке Ионе.

Comment: Майклик, я взялась за позднее Белкино, мне хотелось пронаюлюдать, как её гений трансформирует время; она же, как и поздний Аксёнов, - уже говорит из космоса.

Comment: "Я ни при чём: это занят работой чуждых богов несравненный хорал..."
:)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92343/discussion-between-galina-avanesova-and-michael-1812). Майкл, вот сюда приходи: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1429076-hozhu-po-okolicam-djuzhej-vesny-mozhno-li-najti-v-inete-ssylochku-by-a.html

Comment: Меня компьютер (точнее, Firewall) туда не пускает. Дело в том, что я сейчас на работе и у нас тут ограничения. Можем на выходных побеседовать. Или я могу попробовать зайти туда с домашнего компьютера. (Современного смартфона у меня нет.)